# Socket.io making duplicate when emitting

Tags: javascript, socket.io

### Heading

1. Im emitting games from a .json file, it all works fine
2. When i restart my js code, it emits the games and

   ```
       socket.on('getgames', function (data) {
   socket.emit('updategames', {games:games});
   });
   ```

This is supposed to make a div class="game-:gameid", it works fine until either theres a connection error or i restart my js code. Then it will make duplicate divs and emit it twice, i dont want duplicate.

Comment: You need to explain more in detail what your error is and what you mean by restarting the game.

Please provide more code if possible as well

Comment: Ok i so i have a 'bot' thats made in js. And once i run it it will display the games, in the games.json file. If i turn the bot off and back on, this will duplicate the games and display them twice. Also what code is needed?

Answer (score 0):

This problem will occur then you call on:

```
socket.on('getgames', function (data) {
  socket.emit('updategames', {games:games});
});
```

multiple times. This will course socket.io to subscribe to your event 'getgames' multiple times.

My guess is that you call this code every time you restart your game. To fix it you either unsubscribe from the event or just call the code one time.

Comment: And how would i do this? Can you please write code for me to "unsubscribe from the event or just call the code one time."

Comment: You need to provide more of your code for me to do that.

Comment: Is there any method of contact that we can discuss on? Steam, skype? This way i can provide the full files